# Will OnError in an HttpModule supersede any existing existing error handling?

Tags: c#, asp.net, error-handling, httpmodule, onerror

I have been tasked with creating a sort of global error handling solution, so I'm creating an `HttpModule` to be dropped into an existing ASP.NET solution.  Sometimes these existing web apps will have their own error handling (try/catch) that might do something specific.

**QUESTION** When an app encounters an exception, does the `OnError` in my `HttpModule` fire last since it has more of a global scope than a specific try/catch inside the app?  Will it fire last every single time?  Will `OnError` catch every single application exception, handled AND unhandled?  When I say handled I mean if an error is already "handled" in some section of my code somewhere in my app, will it wind up in `OnError`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your HttpModule will only get those exceptions that are not caught by the application, as is [clearly stated in the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.error%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

If the code that throws an exception is inside a `try...catch` block, there is no exception to be propagated to the global error handler.

If you handle the exception and want to supress the default ASP.NET error message you can do so with the [`ClearError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.clearerror%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

If you really want to know about all exceptions, you can use the [`FirstChanceException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.firstchanceexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event on the `AppDomain` to get notify directly when the exception is caught. Not however that you will probably catch way more exceptions than you expect that way - many exceptions are thrown and gracefully handled within the framework.