# Is there a way for OnError in an HttpModule to catch ALL exceptions, handled AND unhandled?

Tags: c#, asp.net, error-handling, httpmodule, onerror

From what I understand, `OnError` will only be hit in the event of unhandled exceptions in the code.  Handled exceptions will never see `OnError`.  Here's the situation I'm in: I am creating an `HttpModule` to globally handle errors in our existing ASP.NET apps.  But, a lot of these apps already have error handling built in (`try...catch`).  What I want/need is for **ALL** exceptions, handled and/or unhandled, to bubble up the request pipeline to the `HttpModule` `OnError` event.  If this isn't possible, what are some other options, if there are any?  Keep in mind that I need exception details, so `customErrors` in the `web.config` isn't an option.  The goal is to drag/drop the module into our existing applications for easy plug and play, so to speak.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Will OnError in an HttpModule supercede any existing existing error handling?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20003880/will-onerror-in-an-httpmodule-supercede-any-existing-existing-error-handling)

Comment: @AndersAbel This other question is one I asked a few hours ago.  I thought I was asking different things.  I need to know **HOW** to force the OnError to catch all exceptions.